# Can I set custom fonts in TVOS application?

Tags: tvos, custom-font

Like iOS application uses otf fonts and specify same in info.plist. Is the same doable in TVOS application (not tvml)?

Comment: What happened when you tried?

Comment: TVOS supports custom font. I had the issue that otf font file ownership was not added to app target so it was no refected.

Comment: Yes. It's the same as iOS.